# Regex for '/' turns the rest of the line into a comment

Tags: javascript, regex

As can be seen below, I am trying to apply a regex for '/':
[image]

But it's turning the rest of the line into a comment. What's the workaround? Thank you.

*Note: For those wondering, I'm trying to get some info out of the file path name*

Comment: Escaping is using backslash. `\/`

Comment: @Tyr Sorry, I don't know what you mean. This? `(\/(/*)/)`

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the second item in array after splitting `/` characters ? Can you include example of `src` at Question ? , describe expected results ?

Answer (score 12):

If you use a lot of `/` and would rather not escape them all, you can instead avoid using the `/pattern/flags` regex format and use the `RegExp` class constructor, which takes strings where `/` has no special meaning :

```
new RegExp("/(/*)", "i")
```

is equivalent to

```
/\/(\/*)/i
```

Comment: Wow, great alternative. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Just replace every `/` in your regex with `\/` (e.g `/hello//world/g` would become `/hello\/\/world/g`.

**EDIT**: Your Regex would become `/\/(\/*)/`

**EDIT 2**: I also noticed that your are calling `split(/.../[2])`. I think you meant `split(/.../)[2]`

**EDIT 3**: @Aaron's answer is a great alternative as well. If you want to have flags in your regex, `new RegExp("hello", "g")` is equivalent to `/hello/g`

Comment: Thank you, Tupperkion. Saved me from that because I had _just_ got stuck on it when you updated your answer haha.